# CapacitorJS, Can not connect to local backend(Node.js) from Android App

Tags: android, node.js, vue.js, capacitor

I'm developing a Vue.js + node.js(with MongoDB) web site and I also want to create an app for Android and IOS. Currently, I'm working on my local machine (localhost). I converted Vue.js code to Android with Capacitor.js (related link https://morioh.com/p/1ecdd0b4be5c). I tried running it on the emulator and on my physical phone, but the app can not request data from my local backend.
My backend runs on port 3000 and I'm using the cors middleware like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(
    cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: (origin, callback) => {
            callback(null, true);
            },
    })
);
```

Everything works well on the web side.
What should I do or what am I missing? The UI works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can install native-run globally, then use that to serve the backend, then make sure that the frontend on the mobile device connects to that address and port. The mobile device (real or virtual) has to be on the same wifi network. Josh Morony wrote a good explanation of this [here](https://eliteionic.com/tutorials/accessing-localhost-from-mobile-device-ios-android/).

```
npm install -g native-run

ionic cap run android -l --external  # or ios
```

-> Then make sure the frontend is trying to connect to the "external" address and port.